# Logical Block Number and Offset?

Tags: linux, block, offset, inode

I am trying to understand

> Blockquote

how to figure out the logical block number and offset.

```
 Offset from beginning of file: 2000 bytes.
 Block size = 512 bytes.
 2000 / 512 = 3 with a remainder of 464.
 Logical block number = 3.
 Oset within block = 464.
```

So it seems to find this you just divide the Offset from the Block size. But when I do this I get
    `3.90625`.

Why is this different from the example? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain? Still not sure how you get 3.464 when you divide 2000/512? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, missed the point first. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder

Comment: It's hard to explain since we cannot see your sample code ("Blockquote" is displayed instead). But if you are using Python, there is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 regarding division. With Python 2, `2000 / 512 == 3` whereas with Python 3, `2000 / 512 == 3.90625`. To perform an entire division with Python 3, the `//` operator should be used.

Answer (score 0):

3 is the quotient, and 464 is the remainder. To find the remainder, use 2000 mod 512. Using 2000 / 512 is giving you the correct answer but in decimal format.